# Display different maps with slider value mapbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapbox

I have this code down below at the moment and I want to display the div id year 2018 differently based on which value the slider has. So to start the div id year is 2018 if value = 0 and then if value = 1 I want it to be 2019 and so on. Any ideas how to do it? Can I add it to the if statement by using the div based on which slider the if statement is on?

```
<body>
<style>
.map-overlay {
    font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.map-overlay .map-overlay-inner {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.map-overlay h2 {
    line-height: 24px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.map-overlay .legend .bar {
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #fca107, #7f3121);
}

.map-overlay input {
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: ew-resize;
}
</style>    
<div id="map"></div>

<div class="map-overlay top">
    <div class="map-overlay-inner">
        <h2>Year</h2>
        <div id="year">2018</div>
        <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="3" step="1" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="map-overlay-inner">
        <div id="legend" class="legend">
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk....';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container ID
        style: 'mapbox://styles/user/cl38v9w2w000g14p8sd5cqqqp', // style URL
        center: [-105.28461151261762, 40.005493336611714], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 13 // starting zoom
    });

map.on('load', () => {
slider.oninput = function() {
  year.innerHTML = slider.value;
  
  if (slider.value == 0) {
    map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/user/cl38v9w2w000g14p8sd5cqqqp')
  } else if (slider.value == 1) {
    map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11')
  } else if (slider.value == 2) {
    map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11')
  } else if (slider.value == 3) {
    map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10')
  }
}
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your `divs` in `.holder` are in order.
I mean like this:

```
<div class="holder">
<div>2018</div>
<div>2019</div>
<div>2020</div>
<div>2021</div>
</div>
```

```js
const slider = document.getElementById("slider");
const year = document.getElementById("year");

// function to make visible the selected value's div
const show = (i) =>
  (document.querySelectorAll(".holder > div")[i].style.display = "block");
// makes visible the default selected value
// you can change defalut selected value in your html:
// <input id="slider" ... value="0" />
show(parseInt(slider.value));

slider.oninput = function() {
  // makes all divs hidden each time the value changes
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".holder > div")].forEach(
    (i) => (i.style.display = "none")
  );

  const val = parseInt(slider.value);

  // makes visible the selected value's div
  show(val);

  if (val == 0) {
    year.innerHTML = "2018";
  } else if (val === 1) {
    year.innerHTML = "2019";
  } else if (val === 2) {
    year.innerHTML = "2020";
  } else if (val === 3) {
    year.innerHTML = "2021";
  }
};
```

```css
.map-overlay {
  font: 12px/20px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.map-overlay .map-overlay-inner {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.map-overlay h2 {
  line-height: 24px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.map-overlay .legend .bar {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fca107, #7f3121);
}

.map-overlay input {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}


/* makes all divs hidden by default */

.holder>div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div class="map-overlay top">
  <div class="map-overlay-inner">
    <h2>Year</h2>
    <div id="year">2018</div>
    <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="3" step="1" value="0" />
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="map-overlay-inner">
      <div class="legend">
        <h2>2018</h2>
        <p>your content here 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="map-overlay-inner">
      <div class="legend">
        <h2>2019</h2>
        <p>your content here 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="map-overlay-inner">
      <div class="legend">
        <h2>2020</h2>
        <p>your content here 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="map-overlay-inner">
      <div class="legend">
        <h2>2021</h2>
        <p>your content here 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```